# jQuery - Adding an Attribute into Another Attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay - So this might be really simple but I'm pretty new to anything outside of HTML and CSS so I thought it's time I ask :)

So what I want to do is take the contents from a new attribute and add it to the href attribute.

What I have:

```
<div id="testDiv">
    <a href="" newAttr="12345">LINK</a>
</div>

$('#testDiv a').attr('href',newAttr+'.extension');
```

And the outcome I want is:

```
<div id="testDiv">
    <a href="12345.extension" newAttr="12345">LINK</a>
</div>
```

Am I missing something really obvious here or am I miles away?

Any help would be great!

Thanks,
Nick

*EDIT - I was missing an equals sign in this post, not my actual code - Rookie :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the value of an attribute:

```
$('#testDiv a').attr('href', function (i, attr) {
    return $(this).attr('newAttr') + '.extension'
});
```

Btw, you're missing `=` inside your HTML markup:

```
<a href="12345.extension" newAttr="12345">LINK</a>
// ----------------------------- ^ here
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QDA4y/1/)**

---

EDIT: `i` is the index position of your anchor in the set of anchors inside div with id `testDiv`, so in your case it'll be `0` since only one anchor there. In this case, `i` is not compulsory since you don't need to use it at all.

In the other hand, `attr` will return the old `href` value of your anchor. This one is also not needed here since you need the value of `newAttr` not the `href` value, so actually you can just leave both of them as blank:

```
$('#testDiv a').attr('href', function () {
    return $(this).attr('newAttr') + '.extension'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - For some reason it just comes back as undefined.

Comment: Did you check my demo?

Comment: Seems to work now - Are you able to tell me what the (i, val) means.  Or (i, attr)  and why 'i' is actually needed?  Because it seems to work fine with just (attr)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the a variant of the [attribute setter which takes a function as a handler callback](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

```
$('#testDiv a').attr('href', function (i, attr) {
    return $(this).attr('newAttr') + '.extension'
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D9hXT/)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just missing the equal sign for the newAttr?

```
<div id="testDiv">
    <a href="12345.extension" newAttr"12345">LINK</a>
</div>
```

should be

```
<div id="testDiv">
    <a href="12345.extension" newAttr="12345">LINK</a>
</div>
```